# Connect to remote MySQL DB (Linux) from Windows using MySQL Workbench. Remote DB Connection requires local Socket

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, workbench

The Linux Server only allows connection over it's local socket.

```
--socket=/tmp/mysql5.sock
```

I want to connect to the Database using MySQL Workbench, but don't know how to specify the socket path there.
Using the `Standard TCP/IP over SSH` connection I'm providing the SSH connection parameters, Databasename, username, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up an SSH tunnel to the machine:

http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

PuTTY is what I use on Windows when I need to SSH anywhere.  The instructions are fairly thorough.